# Uninstall Python package using pip3

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4, spyder

I am working with Python 3.4 and have installed a package (spyder) using *pip3 install*. It is works as it should and I can start it from the terminal.

Since I want to switch my IDE, I tried to uninstall it using *pip3 uninstall* in the same way as the installation. But this gives me a message that no files can be found.

Here's my terminal output:

```
cord@laptop:~$ sudo pip3 freeze
Coopr==3.5.8748
...
spyder==2.3.4
...
xdiagnose==3.6.3build2
xkit==0.0.0
cord@laptop:~$ sudo pip3 uninstall spyder
Can't uninstall 'spyder'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Any hints?

Comment: What would happen if you remove `sudo`?

Comment: The same: "Can't uninstall 'spyder'. No files were found to uninstall."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to /usr/local/bin and find the packages you want to delete

Then just use `sudo rm -r spyder` or whatever the directory name is.
That way the files get manually removed from your system.

Comment: Meanwhile, I had manually removed them like described in the answer of sagarchalise on the following question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/173323/how-do-i-detect-and-remove-python-packages-installed-via-pip) and forgot about my question here. Thanks anyway!!!